# How do I account for Daylight Savings Time when parsing date/time from a text file?

Tags: python, mongodb, unix-timestamp, dst

I've written a python script to parse raw text into usable data, but the recent DST time change has thrown things off. Here's some of the text, specifically the portion that causes problems:

```
11/1/2015   1:00:37 AM  3.14    0.00    4.18  
11/1/2015   1:30:37 AM  3.14    0.00    4.18  
11/1/2015   1:00:39 AM  3.14    0.00    4.18  
11/1/2015   1:30:39 AM  3.14    0.00    4.18  
11/1/2015   2:00:40 AM  3.14    0.00    4.18
```

The text file gets updated at regular intervals and syncs to dropbox.  On the first run of the script, it populates a mongodb collection with documents that correspond to each line of the file. Each document contains a datetime (for readability in the mongo shell), a timeStamp, and other fields that correspond to the data from the file.

Once the collection is populated, a loop runs every 15 seconds that compares the number of lines in the file to the number of documents in the collection. If the file contains more lines, the script then reads the lowest line in the file and parses it into a document that can be added to the database. It compares the timeStamp of this potential new document to that of the latest document in the collection with

```
if(newdataDate > latestDate):
    db.LiqLog.insert(newdata)
elif(newdataDate < latestDate):
    #Throw error, end script
```

How can I have my script account for changes in the log file due to DST? The only way I can think of is to hard code future DST time changes and work around those. This script will probably run continuously on our lab server for many years, and since I have no way of knowing how long it needs to run for, it would be best for it to be able to handle DST without the need for hard coding dates.

Edit: I found [online](http://www.nist.gov/pml/div688/dst.cfm) that DST always begins on the second Sunday of March and ends on the second Sunday of November. I'm going to try to work with this and I'll edit this post again once I make progress. Thank you all for your help so far.

Comment: Be careful though because the [DST rules changed in 2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_Policy_Act_of_2005) and they could change again in the future.

Answer (score 4):

The best thing to do would be to store all dates & times in UTC, a.k.a. GMT, and to compare them against other UTC times. If you use local time you should also store a time offset or flag to say whether or not the daylight switch has occurred, as some local times are ambiguous e.g. 1:30am on the morning that the clocks go back in the fall, but it gets quite messy though.

Example manipulating time in GMT:

```
import time, calendar
seconds = int(time.time())
print(seconds)
gmtstruct = time.gmtime(seconds)
timeformat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
timestr = time.strftime(timeformat, gmtstruct)
print(timestr + " +0000")
readstruct = time.strptime(timestr, timeformat)
readseconds = calendar.timegm(readstruct)
print(readseconds)
```

Outputs:

```
1447279828
2015-11-11 22:10:28 +0000
1447279828
```

I ran this at 5:10pm local time, which is EST, so the GMT time was formatted as 22:10. I added the "+0000" to indicate that the time zone is GMT for future users of the file.

Comment: So something like:
Check the time difference between UTC and EST time when the loop finds that the log file has a new line, then adjust the date it stores based off of that? Would something like .localize take care of this?

Comment: It should be simpler than that, just use the built in functions and always keep times in UTC internally, and always store it as UTC in your file. I've added an example to my answer, that formats a time to be saved in the file, and parses it again, ending up with the same time value. You can convert to local time for display a user if needed, but in your code only use UTC time.

Comment: Thanks for the input. You're suggesting I change how the log file gets written, right? The file is updated by the software for a helium liquefier and I can't change how it writes to the file. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Well unfortunately the helium liquefier software developers suck ;) You can use e.g. the Pytz module to convert the local times in the file to GMT, but even that module can't correctly handle the one hour per year that is ambiguous. If the timestamps are in order you could use that information to work out the correct daylight savings status of the 01:00 that follows a timestamp of 01:30, but it's quite messy to get that 1 hour per year correct.

Comment: Agreed. I actually had to do a bunch of wonky things to parse the file correctly, like make lists of the locations of all of the tabs, colons, and slashes in the current line and then make strings out of the stuff between certain pairs of those things. It was a good way to start out with Python but I imagine other labs that use liquefiers like this would rather a more usable way of storing data.

Comment: Have you come across regular expresssions? Python has a great `re` module that you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty tricky, because you're not storing datetime objects, but rather flat text. You have to store time zone data in your flat files somehow. I don't there is any other conceivable way to account for DST without that.

Even then, there are some corner cases where you won't be able to figure out which record came before the other. For example:

```
11/1/2015   1:30:39 AM  3.14    0.00    4.18
11/1/2015   1:59:59 AM  3.14    0.00    4.18
```

Assuming we gain an hour at 2AM (i.e., 1:59:59 AM -> 1:00:00 AM,) there is no way to know which record came first as far as I can tell. [Pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) is good for working with timezone data, for whatever that is worth to you.

Comment: If the time stamps are being written to a file sequentially, then the second entry must come after the first, but there is no way to know if they are half an hour apart or 90 minutes apart, unless the next entry is say 01:30 again, in which case you know that they were 30 minutes apart. All very messy.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I used pytz originally, but I couldn't get it to work the way I wanted it to so I switched to using timeStamps. I edited the original post with a possible solution, and I'll edit again with an update.

Comment: @Galax - Yes, that is a good approach, but of course, it depends on having data that is out of sequence in the file (data written both before and after the transition during the ambiguous period).  In this example there is, but in the generic case it might be that there was activity only on one side of the transition - in which case you can't tell which side it was on. :)

Comment: Yes, although if the file is checked every 15 seconds you can tell when the data was written by when it appeared in the file. All ugly hacks to workaround a flaw in the data format.

Comment: @Galax, you know can know when the entry was written, but how do you classify the entry semantically? Should an entry written at 1:59AM be placed before or after an entry written at 1:30AM? Even if the event at 1:59 'truly' (for lack of a better word) took place before before the event at 1:30, you still have a confusing entry in your log. It is not an easy problem to solve.

Comment: The entries will written to the file in the order that they occur. A 'confusing entry' (which has a lower numeric value for local time than a previous entry) will indicate that either an error (such as a change to the device's internal clock) or the fall daylight switch occurred.

Comment: Your question "Should an entry written at 1:59AM be placed before or after an entry written at 1:30AM?" doesn't make sense, because you said that you can't modify the device that writes the log entries- how can you decide which order it should write them in?

Comment: @Galax, the condition `elif(newdataDate < latestDate): #Throw error, end script` is what is complicating things here. If you just print the dates to a file, parsing will throw and error. If you reorder them, then you can't tell which entry came first.

Comment: If you print the dates to a file yourself, convert them to UTC first as I originally mentioned and everything will be fine from that point on.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler answer is to change your script to:

```
if(newdataDate > latestDate):
    db.LiqLog.insert(newdata)
elif(newdataDate < latestDate):
    print("Warning: DST switch detected")
    db.LiqLog.insert(newdata)
```

Are there any other error conditions that could cause the new date in the file to be earlier than the last date?

Why do you need to check the date at all? If an extra line has been written to the file, is there always new data to insert?